# How much overhead does an HTTP request to a local Node.js server add

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, electron

I have a function, which reads files from a local ZIP archive, using a stream, and returns them

```
function readFileFromZip (response) {
  zipReader.pipe(response);
}
```

How much faster would running `readFileFromZip()` be on the frontend **vs** making an AJAX request from the frontend to a localhost Node.js server, running `readFileFromZip` there, and receiving a response?

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  readFileFromZip(response);
});

server.listen(8000);
```

The frontend is wrapped with Electron, so no need to worry about browser security restricitons.  The files are a few MB in size.  Is it correct to assume that the local HTTP overhead will be negligible relative to read time from disk on most home PCs?

Comment: If you really want to know in your particular environment with your particular server, then just measure the difference in response time.  We can't really tell you, because the difference is environment-specific.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to measure it.. would depend on quite a bit.. biggest thing is going to be how much data is sent and how many times.  But the browser, network setup, etc. can vary quite a bit.  Network can be orders of magnitude slower than CPU, but on local and doing only one iteration the time for network  it could be nearly imperceptible if the data is small.

Need details and then profile it in the environment.